# X++: Highlighting all records in a grid from a code (including not loaded ones)

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I can't workout this seemingly simple task. I have a custom CheckBox named PrintAll and what I want is once it gets selected, all rows in a grid gets selected/highlighted. Here's what I have tried:

**Option 1:** Passing CTRL+SHIFT+END. The example below passes CTRL+A combination.

```
public boolean modified()
{
    boolean ret;

    ret = super();
    #task

    if(PrintAll.value())
    {
        // CTRL+A
        element.task(#taskSelectAll);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

***Result:*** selects only loaded records, so say 20 out of 500. If you scroll down, it keeps selecting upcoming ones.

CTRL+SHIFT+END combination works from UI, although it gives this Box::yesNo:

> You cannot select all lines including the last one, as not all the
>   lines have been loaded at the present time.  Loading all the lines may
>   take some time!
>
> Do you want to continue selecting lines and to load all lines now?

When I tested what `taskid` CTRL+SHIFT+END gets, it appears that it gets 2842, unfortunately using this id in code as `element.task(2842);` highlights only the first record.

So if instead of CTRL+A I could submit CTRL+SHIFT+END properly, the problem would be solved.

**EDIT:** ***(PARTIAL SOLUTION)*** Running `element.task(2842);` twice gets me to the warning above, so I can click Yes and select all the lines. Does anyone know how could I bypass this warning?

**Option 2:** Trying various properties of the form and data sources to make it to load all the records available and not the first 20.

***Result:*** nothing has worked.

**Option 3:** Perhaps the CheckBox, which can be found on some forms as a first field and which, once selected, selects all the records, could do the same, but I can't find how to add it to my custom form? Although perhaps this option select loaded records only too, so it won't make a difference to what I have now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what finally worked for me ([source](http://www.stoneridgesoftware.com/ax-2012-forms-marking-records-on-a-form-data-source/)). Please note, that InventDim wasn't my main Data Source in this form. InventTransOrigin was the one, but it didn't worked.

So I guess, you can have this method if you don't want to show any warnings to the end user:

```
public boolean modified()
{
    InventDim    inventDimTMP;

    boolean ret;

    ret = super();

    if(PrintAll.value())
    {
        inventDimTMP = InventDim_DS.getFirst();

        while(inventDimTMP)
        {
            InventDim_DS.findRecord(inventDimTMP);
            InventDim_DS.mark(true);
            inventDimTMP = InventDim_DS.getNext();
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

OR this one if you want them to see the warning mentioned above:

```
public boolean modified()
{
    boolean ret;

    ret = super();

    if(PrintAll.value())
    {
        // Marks first record
        element.task(2842);
        // Marks all records
        element.task(2842);
    }

    return ret;
}
```